# Scrapy returning items within spider before first request/parse

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to return some items from inside a spider before starting to parse requests. Because I need to make sure some parent items exist in database before parsing child items.

I now yield them from the `parse` method first thing, and this seem to work fine. But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of yielding the items, write them into the database directly on the constructor of the pipeline where you add regular items to the database.

Comment: Do you mean constructor of the spider? (I updated the question to clarify I need to return them from spider) 2 problems 1: the settings are not read yet and I can't get database settings. 2: I have several pipelines and I would need to call them one by one. I am able to access settings from custom `start_requests` but still problem 2 remains. It does not allow yielding from `start_requests`. I am not sure how to automatically send an item to pipelines listed in settings. (other than yielding it)

Comment: I mean the constructor of the pipeline that sends items from the spider to the database. Pipelines can access settings through the crawler, check the documentation for information about that; that solves problem 1. The only pipeline that you need to modify is the database one; problem 2 should not be a problem at all.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to connect the dots here. How am I suppose to send the items from the spider class to the constructor of the pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize the first wave of items were also scraped, I though they would be hardcoded items. You said “I need to return some items from inside a spider before starting to parse requests”; I though those initial items did not came from requests. Do they?